# Illegal String Offset in Models Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Pls help me i having trouble, i have models and error, pls help me

```
 public function website_footer() {
   $data = '';
    $settings = $this->check_settings_exist(13);
    if ($settings != false) {
        $setting_details = $this->objectToArray(json_decode('[' . $settings . ']'));
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($setting_details[0] as $key => $value) {
            if ($i == count($setting_details[0])) {
                $data[$key] = $value;
            } else {
               $data[$key   ] = $value;
            }
            ++$i;
        }
        return $data;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Error :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Illegal string offset 'website_footer'
>
> Filename: models/Write_setting_model.php
>
> Line Number: 97

Comment: Are you sure the error happens in the code you posted? Which of those lines is line 97? Is it the `Write_setting_model.php` file?

Comment: yup sir is right code

Comment: So which of these is line 97? I don't see anywhere where that error could be thrown.

Comment: u can see on this link sir, im sory about my question if me wrong 
[link] (https://imgur.com/a/H2gudmJ)

Comment: What i mean is: In the code you posted, which of those lines is 97? Because in the code you posted nothing should go wrong.

Comment: best thing is to add that model code here.write_setting_model or the query you are executing. that should give us some details on it